# Architecture of independent API access layer between DB and front end

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've recently heard about a company using a surprising architecture pattern of a stand alone /independent API (access layer) between a very poorly structured SQL Server and their front end, such that NO entity framework is used anywhere as well as having no direct interaction with the DB from the front end.

I've never seen this before in a .Net Core/Framework environment and comes across as a plaster type situation where they are trying to abstract away the poor DB structure and hide it from the consumer via the API, instead of fixing the core issue, which is the poor DB.

Is this considered an actual architecture pattern or best practice (in this situation even perhaps?) or is this just a mess? The development team seems adamant on this new API pattern...

Comment: How fast is the API?  What connection string/driver is being used?  I suspect they are using ODBC instead of OleDb.  ODBC is older/faster than OleDb.  When OleDb first came out is was supposed to be a great replacement for ODBC, but many companies went back to ODBC due to speed issues.  So a database tool is only good as the time it takes to perform a query.

Comment: This question really belongs on SE Stack: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard practice to abstract the front end from the database. Layers of abstractions make render data transport objects that differ wildly from the entity models in the database. This insulating layer provides a set standard for actors attempting to access the data and encapsulates business logic in a central location. This is a smart decision. As the database standards are improved, the API calls to the database can be updated without affecting the front end. Thus, front end developers need not be bothered with schematic database changes. Entity Framework is not a pre or co requisite for c# projects communicating with databases. There are many ORM libraries out there and some stacks don't even leverage one. While EF is powerful, if the database is a mess, it may be prudent to delay implementation of any ORM until the data and schema is sufficiently curated.